# x86 assembly: incremeting a variable

Tags: assembly, vector, crash

I'm trying to make a snake game in assembly language, but I am getting a "snake.exe has stop working" error

```
.data
snake DD 50 DUP(0) ; here will be saved the body of the snake
dimension DD 0

.code
grow_body proc
pop edx
lea esi, snake

cmp dimension, 0
je add_to_body

mov eax, dimension
mov ecx, 4
mul ecx
add esi, eax

mov ecx, dimension
shift_body:
mov ebx, dword ptr[esi-4]
mov dword ptr[esi], ebx
sub esi, 4
loop shift_body

add_to_body:
;inc dimension   ; <------------PROBLEM
lea esi, snake  
get_position_macro snakeHeadX, snakeHeadY
mov ebx, position
mov dword ptr[esi], ebx

push edx
ret
grow_body endp
```

If i use
    inc dimension
the program doesnt work, but if i comment that line, the program works. 
In addition to that, even if i use
    add dimension, 1
I still get that error.

I need to increment somehow the dimension. What could I make to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some more info; like how are you limiting `dimension` not to exceed 50, and what is the value of `dimension` when the program fails? And a tip: to load `esi` with the address of `snake` plus `dimension *4` you could use `mov ecx,dimension` / `lea esi,[snake + ecx*4]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When the program fails, dimension is still 0. So, when I move the snake's head on the food I have to grow the body, thus increment the dimension. And when I reach the first food, I get the crash message.

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Comment: _"when I reach the first food, I get the crash"_ So it's crashing in some code that you haven't shown in your question? That makes it pretty much impossible for anyone reading your question to know what the problem might be.

Comment: Please add the code for `get_position_macro`. If `grow_body proc` is a procedure that is `call`'ed, why you `pop edx`? You'll get `eip` stored by `call`, but why? Also, you end `grow_body` with `push edx`, `ret`. If you don't modify `edx` in between, you'll return to the instruction after the `call`, as usual. But if you do modify `edx`, `ret` returns somewhere else, and a crash is probable. You can modify the return address that way, but I see here no reason for that. So leave those `pop edx` and `push edx` out. The bug might be in the `get_position_macro` macro. Debug the code to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The program fails when I increment the dimension. If I delete that line, the program works just fine. @nrz: I was saving the return adress in edx, so that when grow_body ends, i know where to return. I know that I can't change edx in that proc.

Comment: The probability that your program crashes _at the instruction_ that increments `dimension` is pretty much nil. Your program may well be crashing (somewhere else in your code) _as a result of_ you having incremented `dimension`, but you need to locate the exact line where the crash occurs and include that piece of code in your question.

Comment: If it crashes in the line of the `inc dimensions` you would have an invalid DS register.